# Fuzzy Logic lookup

Tags: sql, fuzzy-logic

[image: The table]

Hello, as per the attached image, we are trying to update a 1.7million row UK postcode table with insurance risk groups. There are several thousand New Postcodes with no groupNumber and these appear as NULL. Want to replace the NULLs with the value from the postcode in the row above. 
Believe we should be using some sort of fuzzy logic but need some help please.
Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

In a query, you can do:

```
select t.*, 
       coalesce(groupnumber, lag(groupnumber) over (order by new_postcode)) as new_groupnumber
from t;
```

It is not clear if you want to actually change the data or just return the values in a query.

Comment: I think is refering for an `update`. Plus you should order by the first column that looks like some sort of an `identifier`

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy logic is about writing rules in structured English. These rules can be understood by man and machine at the same time and are easily adjusted to further requirements. A rule for replacing the NULL postcode can be written in Forth:

```
OrigPostcode NULL = IF
  row_above OrigPostcode
  row_above groupnumber
THEN
```

The term “row_above” is a linguistic variable. And above means that the index is i-1 with 0.9 affiliation.

Instead of formulating the rule manually, it's also possible to use a technique called “Learning from demonstration”. That means a human operator is doing the copy&paste task first and the system will recognize the rule autonomously. This is usually done with neural networks and described in open access journals freely available in the Internet provided by predatory publishing groups.